# .NET Poll w/ jQuery - Tweet/Post to Facebook and Twitter

Tags: jquery, .net, facebook, twitter

I have a more generic question, so I'm hoping someone here has some info on my dilemma. I'm thinking about creating a .NET jQuery Poll:

> One question with a few choices. Once the user chooses an option, the
>   results will show a calculated projection of all choices that have already been chosen. I would also like the user to be able to share their
>   results (and possibly what they chose) via Facebook and Twitter and drive people to the page so that they can make a choice too.

I've done some Googling, but nothing comes up with the ability to post/share via social networks. Does anyone know of a jQuery plugin that already exists, or possibly a website that already does this? Trying to figure out the best method of combining jQuery, .NET, and FB/Twitter sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit of tweaking and this example helped achieve the above. In case any one comes across this and needs a solution, here ya go: I haven't gotten it to share yet, but it's a start:

http://clientsideasp.deynu.com/poll/Poll_CS.aspx